# AudioStreamPlayer getting treated as "null" and refusing to play

Tags: godot, godot4

I am trying to set up my game to play a specific song during a match, and then switch to different songs at the end depending on which character won (those being just placeholders here for now).  I have this code in a script that I plan to call methods from in the script for the main game loop as needed:

```
extends AudioStreamPlayer

class_name Sounds

enum CURRENT_SONG {MATCH, CHAR1, CHAR2}

@onready var matchMusic: AudioStreamPlayer = $MatchMusic

func playMusic(song := CURRENT_SONG.MATCH) -> void:
    match song:
        CURRENT_SONG.MATCH:
            matchMusic.play()
        CURRENT_SONG.CHAR1:
            pass
        CURRENT_SONG.CHAR2:
            pass
```

I have an AudioStreamPlayer node in the scene tree named "MatchMusic" with a placeholder song attached.

I watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6-2Iwb8xoU), where something similar to what I'm doing above worked, and changed things around to attach sound playback to certain steps in the gameplay loop instead of just clicking a button.  Instead, when I attempt to run my game, I get the error "Cannot call method 'play' on a null value."
I tested commenting out the matchMusic.play() method, replacing it with a print statement, and running it then, to make sure it's not just a problem with how I'm trying to call my playMusic() function somehow- that part seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your node path correct? The message means that the matchMusic variable resolved to null. It's possible there is a typo in the name, or the node is located elsewhere. $MatchMusic is equivalent to the get_node("MatchMusic") call, so it looks for the node with that name in the children of the node which has your script attached to it.

Comment: I've now rearranged my scene tree to make sure the MatchMusic node is a child of this one, and right-clicked + copied node path to make sure there's no typos, but I'm still getting the same error.  Could there be anything else that might've slipped my mind?  I'm still pretty new to the node system and all

Comment: I have another idea (an something which I rutinely shoot myself in the foot with): when is this piece of code called? It's possible the AudioStreamPlayer is not yet initialized when this is called. Since it is a child node of the script, anything after and includeing _ready() of the script is fine. I can only think of _init() which is called before the child's ready.

Comment: I thought that might be it but it somehow still gave me an error with my Sounds class script.  _But,_ luckily in trying to figure that out, it looks like just moving this function (and all the initialization stuff you suggested) over to the script I'm trying to call it in instead works!  It's going to make things a little more cluttered there, but I'm just glad it's functioning now.